# Reduce horizontal whitespace in aligned equation

Tags: equations, align, white-space

I am using the following code to create an aligned equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Z_costumpreamble}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align} % equation 3
    Y\textsubscript{i,P}~=~\beta\textsubscript{0}~
    &+ \beta\textsubscript{1} B\textsubscript{ij}
    &+& \beta\textsubscript{2} B\textsubscript{ij} \cdot R\textsubscript{i} \nonumber \\
    &+      \beta\textsubscript{3} \Delta\textsubscript{P\textsubscript{ij}}
    &+& \beta\textsubscript{4} B\textsubscript{ij} \cdot M\textsubscript{n} \nonumber \\
    &+  \beta\textsubscript{5} B\textsubscript{ij} \cdot R\textsubscript{i} \cdot M\textsubscript{n}
    &+& \beta\textsubscript{6}\Delta\textsubscript{P\textsubscript{ij}} \cdot M\textsubscript{n} \nonumber \\
    &+  \varepsilon\textsubscript{i} \label{eq:Ap1_m3}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: resulting formula]

I would, however like to reduce the whitespace between both columns (i.e. before the second "+" in each row) while keeping the entries aligned vertically, as by the code.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant that places the equation number differently:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Ap1_m3}
    \begin{aligned} % equation 3
Y_{i,P} = \beta_{0} &+ \beta_{1} B_{ij}          &&+ \beta_{2} B_{ij} \cdot R_{i}  \\
                    &+ \beta_{3} \Delta_{P_{ij}} &&+ \beta_{4} B_{ij} \cdot M_{n}  \\
                    &+  \beta_{5} B_{ij} \cdot R_{i} \cdot M_{n} &&+ \beta_{6}\Delta_{P_{ij}} \cdot M_{n} \\
          &+  \varepsilon_{i} 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]